# How do I use querySelector to find elements with a number of possible values for a given attribute?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, queryselector

This gives me all MyElement elements with a value of '1' for the MyAttribute attribute:

```
xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("MyElement[MyAttribute='1']")
```

But what gives me elements with a value of '1' *or* '2'?

Comment: `MyElement[MyAttribute='1'], MyElement[MyAttribute='2']` or `MyElement[MyAttribute]` and then filter

Comment: The part behind the equal sign you can update to the value you are looking for